# Cookie created with cookie-universal-nuxt tagged with HttpOnly is only displayed after page refresh

Tags: cookies, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm creating a **VUE/NUXT 2.XX (SSR)** application and I have an authentication logic working with **JWT Token** that after authenticating the user I create a cookie storing the value of the token to get it after the page refresh.
Cookies are working normally, however when setting **HttpOnly=true** as a property of the **"cookie-universal-nuxt"** library after a this.$router.replace('/dashboar') or this.$router.push('/dashboad') the cookie is not displayed, only if you press **"F5" (refresh the page)**. If I set the property to **HttpOnly=false** the cookie is displayed normally and I can retrieve it on other pages.

Another behavior I've noticed is that direct user actions such as "exit" are not deleting the cookie marked HttpOnly=true, the inversion is not true. Simple cookies are being deleted when the user clicks to leave the page as this is the logic I implemented.

[after login single cookies are displayed normally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAAjO.png)

[after login, if i refresh the page the cookie is displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGUTr.png)

**Someone implementing a similar solution using cookies and nuxt went through something similar and managed to solve it?**

Comment: The behavior of HTTP only is looking like it's working as expected so far. What is the issue?

Comment: I don't understand, is this the behavior of creating an httpOnly cookie?
is it only visible after page refresh?

Comment: Did you read the documentation regarding [`HttpOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies)?

Comment: Eu resolvi a essa questão implementando o cookie httpOnly por meio do servidor.
Neste caso, a minha API BackEnd JAVA.

Comment: In english please.

Comment: I solved this issue by implementing the httpOnly cookie through the server. In this case, my BackEnd JAVA API